# SQL Server - assign day and night

Tags: sql-server

I have following 2019 data.

```
Date         Calendar_year Weekend_indicator
2019-01-01   2019          weekday
2019-01-01   2019          weekday
2019-01-02   2019          weekday
2019-01-02   2019          weekday
```

and so on.

I need to give one record a day and another a night value and have it repeated for the entire year's data so that it would look like this.

```
    Date     Calendar_year Weekend_indicator     day_night
2019-01-01   2019          weekday                Day
2019-01-01   2019          weekday                Night
2019-01-02   2019          weekday                Day
2019-01-02   2019          weekday                Night
```

Here is my code.

```
DECLARE @Year AS INT,
@FirstDateOfYear DATETIME,
@LastDateOfYear DATETIME
-- You can change @year to any year you desire
SELECT @year = 2019
SELECT @FirstDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900, 0)
SELECT @LastDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900 + 1, 0)
-- Creating Query to Prepare Year Data;
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 AS DayID,
@FirstDateOfYear AS FromDate,
DATENAME(dw, @FirstDateOfYear) AS Dayname
UNION ALL
SELECT cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate),
DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
FROM cte
WHERE DATEADD(d,1,cte.FromDate) < @LastDateOfYear
)
SELECT c.FromDate AS Date
,@Year as calendar_year
,CHOOSE(datepart(dw, c.FromDate), 'WEEKEND', 'WEEKDAY', 'WEEKDAY', 
'WEEKDAY', 'WEEKDAY', 'WEEKDAY', 'WEEKEND') as weekend_indicator 
FROM CTE c
CROSS JOIN ( values (1), (2) ) tb (FromDate)
WHERE DayName IN ('Saturday','Sunday') 
or dayname not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
order by c.FromDate
OPTION (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

How do I assign the day and the night value and have it repeated?

Answer (score 2):

This simple query might point you in the right direction:

```
USE TEMPDB

CREATE TABLE #T (DateCol DATE, Calender_Year INT)
INSERT INTO #T VALUES ('20180101', 2018 )

SELECT * 
FROM #T
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Day'), ('Night') ) AS C (Val)
```

Comment: The OP's code already have CROSS JOIN ( values (1), (2) ) tb (FromDate), all that he need is to decode 1 and 2 as day and night

Answer (score 2):

If you want just to change your code without rewriting it, 
add one more row as below:

```
DECLARE @Year AS INT,
@FirstDateOfYear DATETIME,
@LastDateOfYear DATETIME
-- You can change @year to any year you desire
SELECT @year = 2019
SELECT @FirstDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900, 0)
SELECT @LastDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900 + 1, 0);
-- Creating Query to Prepare Year Data;
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 1 AS DayID,
@FirstDateOfYear AS FromDate,
DATENAME(dw, @FirstDateOfYear) AS Dayname
UNION ALL
SELECT cte.DayID + 1 AS DayID,
DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate),
DATENAME(dw, DATEADD(d, 1 ,cte.FromDate)) AS Dayname
FROM cte
WHERE DATEADD(d,1,cte.FromDate) < @LastDateOfYear
)
SELECT c.FromDate AS Date
,@Year as calendar_year
,CHOOSE(datepart(dw, c.FromDate), 'WEEKEND', 'WEEKDAY', 'WEEKDAY', 
'WEEKDAY', 'WEEKDAY', 'WEEKDAY', 'WEEKEND') as weekend_indicator,
case tb.FromDate when 1 then 'Day' else 'Night' end as day_night -----<<<<<<-----
FROM CTE c
CROSS JOIN ( values (1), (2) ) tb (FromDate)
WHERE DayName IN ('Saturday','Sunday') 
or dayname not in ('Saturday', 'Sunday')
order by c.FromDate
OPTION (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use a table variable for create this solution.

```
DECLARE 
     @Year int
    ,@FirstDateOfYear date
    ,@LastDateOfYear date
    ,@date_loop date

SET @YEAR = 2019

SELECT 
     @FirstDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900, 0)
    ,@LastDateOfYear = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900 + 1, 0)
    ,@date_loop = DATEADD(yyyy, @Year - 1900, 0) --initialize variable for loop

DECLARE @date_table TABLE ([Date] date, [Calendar_year] int, [Weekend_indicator] varchar(10), [day_night] varchar(5))

WHILE @date_loop < @LastDateOfYear
BEGIN
    INSERT @date_table

    SELECT d.[Date], d.[Calendar_year], d.[Weekend_indicator], ca.[day_night]
    FROM (
    SELECT  
         @date_loop AS [Date]
        ,YEAR(@date_loop) AS [Calendar_year]
        ,CHOOSE(datepart(dw, @date_loop), 'weekend', 'weekday', 'weekday','weekday', 'weekday', 'weekday', 'weekend') AS [Weekend_indicator]) AS d
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT 'Day' AS [day_night]
        UNION
        SELECT 'Night'
    ) AS ca

    SET @date_loop = DATEADD(day,1,@date_loop)
END

SELECT *
FROM @date_table
```

Answer (score 1):

*Revised answer:* I see an unused `(VALUES ...)` clause which could be used like so:

```
CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('Day'), ('Night') ) whatever(day_night)
```

[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c891319f088439c1a605c4cd11c4985f)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a calendar or numbers table, you can use an ad-hoc table

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 date = '2019-01-01'
Declare @Date2 date = '2019-12-31'

Select [Date] = d
      ,Calendar_year     = datepart(YEAR,d)
      ,Weekend_indicator = case when datename(WEEKDAY,d) in ('Saturday','Sunday') then 'weekend' else 'weekday' end
      ,day_night
 From  (
        Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,@Date1,@Date2)+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
         From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
       ) A
 Cross Join (values ('Day'),('Night') ) b(day_night)
 Order by D,day_night
```

**Returns**

```
Date        Calendar_year  Weekend_indicator   day_night
2019-01-01  2019           weekday             Day
2019-01-01  2019           weekday             Night
2019-01-02  2019           weekday             Day
2019-01-02  2019           weekday             Night
...
2019-12-30  2019           weekday             Day
2019-12-30  2019           weekday             Night
2019-12-31  2019           weekday             Day
2019-12-31  2019           weekday             Night
```